# callback function for `scroll` event doesn't get covered by enzyme test. (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, enzyme

This is my part of React component

```
...
  componentDidMount(): void {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true);
  }

  handleScroll() {
     const hello = 'assign';
     this.setState({blah: 'blah'}); /// whole function is not covered.
  }
...
```

enzyme test

```
describe('when is scrolled', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper.simulate('scroll', true); <-- simulate scroll
  });

  test('should match snapshot', () => {
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot(); <<< should cover `handleScroll`
  })
});
```

This should cover `handleScroll` but enzyme test doesn't cover the whole function (for code coverage)

Comment: this is sooo weird

Answer (score 0):

You bind the `scroll` event on the `window` object, NOT the component wrapper. You can mock the `window.addEventListener()` method and trigger it manually.

E.g.

`MyComponent.ts`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    blah: '',
  };
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleScroll = this.handleScroll.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount(): void {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll, true);
  }

  handleScroll() {
    const hello = 'assign';
    this.setState({ blah: 'blah' });
  }
  render() {
    return <div>{this.state.blah}</div>;
  }
}
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

describe('66484613', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const addEventListenerSpy = jest.spyOn(window, 'addEventListener').mockImplementationOnce((_, handler) => {
      if (typeof handler === 'function') {
        handler({} as Event);
      }
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent />);
    expect(wrapper.state('blah')).toBe('blah');
    expect(addEventListenerSpy).toBeCalledWith('scroll', expect.any(Function), true);
    addEventListenerSpy.mockRestore();
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66484613/MyComponent.test.tsx
  66484613
    ✓ should pass (7 ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 MyComponent.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.913 s, estimated 4 s
```